# Обновление jar файла

Tags: java

Можно ли как-нибудь просто обновить jar файл во время его выполнения? Вот например, если есть новая версия программы, то я ее качаю, выхожу из программы и запускаю.

Comment: В общем вы можете легко реализовать вышеописанный механизм своими руками. Обновление кода на ходу [существует](http://hotswapagent.org/), но вам придется изрядно попотеть, чтобы это работало незаметно для пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, этого нельзя сделать. Нужно заново запускать приложение.

Чтобы снизить неудобства от этого факта, рекомендую ознакомиться с [Inversion of Control](https://habrahabr.ru/post/131993/), который предписывает выносить всю статическую информацию (настройки, пути, прочую информацию) в отдельные файлы и БД.